# Visual Studio showing wrong values while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I was debugging my code when I saw something weird. Basically it came down to this:

[image: Weirdness]

What you see here is an unsigned int with a negative value...

I also noticed that some surrounding variables didn't have a `value pop-up`(?) and others did. But this variable was the only one that had an impossible value.

**How is this possible?**

<sub>I only have C# Visual Studio 2010, so I don't know it this problem exists in other versions or for different languages. I'll change the title and tags accordingly if this is the case.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

While debugging, Visual Studio will keep track of every variable in the current context.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
void SomeMethod1()
{
    int j = 0;
}

void SomeMethod2()
{
    int i = 0;
}//Breakpoint on this line.
```

When the program breaks, the current context is `SomeMethod2`. At this point the developer is unable to check what the value of `j` would be. This is because `int j` **is not a variable in the current context.**

**The actual reason behind OP's described behavior:**

> Visual Studio checks if the **name** of the variable exists in the current context and **doesn't check** if the **variable itself** exists in the current context.

So if we change the name of variable `j` to `i` in `SomeMethod1`, we can suddenly view its "value". Imagine how weird it would get if `i` in `SomeMethod2` was a string:

[image]

**When should you know this?**

Whenever you have a piece of code where it's not immediately clear what the current context is. I encountered this problem in the following piece of code:

```
private double CalculateFast(double d)
{
    //Depending on the size of d, either [Method 1] or [Method 2] is faster.
    //Run them both and use the answer of the first method to finish.
    Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() = >
    {
        //Method 1   
    }

    //Method 2

    return answer;
}
```

I was debugging `Method 2` but I thought I could view the variables of `Method 1` as well. But this wasn't the case because `Method 1` has its own context.

Comment: 1. It's called "Visual Studio". 2. How is this a bug?

Comment: 1. Edited. 2. A software bug is an error, flaw, failure, or fault in a computer program or system that produces an incorrect or unexpected result. I'd say the results are unexpected. And I never called it an absolute bug.

Comment: That definition does not apply here. There is no error or fault in Visual Studio in this regard. Your expectations are wrong, that's not a bug. ;-) If you replace the VS2010 tag with "Visual Studio" and remove all references to "bug" I'll give you an upvote, as this is a good reference question with this extensive answer.

Comment: I'd back the differ. If a blind man would show me a cat and then tells me it's a dog, he is wrong. Despite my expectation that he would say that he is holding a cat. But I am willing to describe it differently ;-)

Comment: If a program does not meet user expectations, users will call it a bug. Whether it is a designed feature that they think should do something different (works as designed-user education probably required), or a designed feature that is not correctly doing what it should (a bug in functionality), users do not know the difference. So don't be surprised or get mad when users report features or normal behavior as a bug--- just educate them, very politely.

Comment: @StarPilot, are you saying they purposely designed it to work like this? Because I am finding it difficult to see the logic.

Comment: In a nutshell (there's a little more to it):  on a breakpoint, execution is paused. You only are inspecting the current stack. The debugger does not know about functions or their local variables not on the stack. If you inspect a variable in a different function or another class that coincidentally has the same name, it can either show an error ("this one isn't in this stack") or show the variable with the same name that is.

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

- Clean solution
- Rebuild solution
- In no success - kill PDB files manually (or entire bin and obj folders) and rebuild

Hope that helps.

Comment: CodeCaster. I had similar situation in the past. My bool variable was always false in debugger, even after I explicitly set it to true. The problem was - Visual Studio stopped updating PDB files for some reasons. After I delete them manually, everithing becomes wroking as expected.

Comment: That still is an entirely different problem. OP has two same-name variables in different contexts. No matter how many times you delete the PDB's and rebuild, the result will stay the same.