# Debugging 64bit DLL inspector showing incorrect values

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017, 64-bit, visual-studio-debugging

I've built a 64 bit version of the OpenH264 DLL in debug mode (with no compiler optimisations) and am calling it in C# (via Unity). I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to attach to the running Unity process and debug my dll.

I can place breakpoints and step through the code, however all values for the code seem to be random (or sometimes null).

For example [this is where the debugger reports NULL as the value of a pointer but is stopped on the line after a failed NULL check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXpHN.png).

Why is this happening and what can I do to get correct values when inspecting variables?

Comment: Another example: in  `CWelsH264SVCEncoder::Initialize` WelsLog is called with the define WELS_LOG_INFO (which is 4), but several statements into the WelsLog function the inspector reports iLevel to have a value of 0.

Comment: Additionally while debugging this I noticed that the debugger steps weirdly, for example in the switch statement of the WelsLog function, the debugger steps into the default case before jumping back to the switch statement and then continuing into the WELS_LOG_INFO case (which is the correct one).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to ["At this time, Visual Studio Tools for Unity only supports managed DLLs. It does not support debugging of native code DLLs, such as those written in C++."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn940020.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1)

Comment: I'm not using visual studio tools for unity for the debugging though. I'm attaching using the Visual Studio debugger by setting the C++ project as the startup project and then using `Debug->Attach to Process` and selecting the Unity Editor from the list of processes.

Answer (score 0):

1 Please try to switch the **Common Language Runtime Support** under **Configuration Properties** :
[image]

2 Another potential reason is that the variable is not in the current context:

[While debugging, Visual Studio will keep track of every variable in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126643/9125096)

Comment: 1. Wouldn't that just convert the unmanaged C++ dll to a managed C++ dll? I won't be able to use a managed C++ dll in the final product, would that potentially introduce different errors or mask existing errors? How would this make inspecting variables start working?

Comment: 2. As for your second point, pretty sure the variable is in scope in the line I'm stopped on in the screenshot (since it's used on that line). As for all of the other examples, I'm either stopped on a line that uses the variable or a line that's in-between two uses of the variable in the same function.

Comment: Another question for the first one -  How would this make inspecting variables start working if there are no accompanying code changes?

Comment: @StephOpaque  Managed code benefits from features such as cross-language integration, cross-language exception handling, and debugging and profiling services. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr And it's not necessary, but based on the issue i just come up that idea. If it's not working, i also wonder if you've enabled mixed-mode debugging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode

Comment: Unfortunately I've been pulled off the project. I'm going to pass your suggestion onto the person who's continuing the project, but I can't guarantee they'll get back to this question. Thanks for your suggestions nevertheless.

Comment: Also for record's sake, I did have mixed mode debugging turned on on the C# project, but I was debugging using the C++ project and didn't see an equivalent option.

Comment: For Mix option in VC++ project: Configuration properties -> Debugging-> Debugger typer